# Jekyll, embed html as string

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have a html snippet in a markdown file in jekyll, the problem is that when it gets parsed, liquid tries to parse it, is there anyway I can tell liquid not to parse a specific line or block?

```
public render() {
  <ExifOrientationImg markdown="span" src={img} style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%', objectFit: 'cover' }} />
}
```

throws:

````
    Liquid Warning: Liquid syntax error (line 25): Expected end_of_string but found colon in "{{ height: '100%', width: '100%', objectFit: 'cover' }}" in /Users/osp/dev/githubpage/_posts/2019-08-27-react-rotating-image.md
    Liquid Warning: Liquid syntax error (line 63): Expected end_of_string but found colon in "{{width: '100%', height: '100%', display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}" in /Users/osp/dev/githubpage/_posts/2019-08-27-react-rotating-image.md
    Liquid Warning: Liquid syntax error (line 86): Expected end_of_string but found colon in "{{maxWidth: '100%', maxHeight: '100%'}}" in /Users/osp/dev/githubpage/_posts/2019-08-27-react-rotating-image.md
                    ...done in 0.138611 seconds.```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `{% raw %}` [liquid tag](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/tags/raw/) disables Liquid parsing :

```
{% raw %}
public render() {
  <ExifOrientationImg markdown="span" src={img} style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%', objectFit: 'cover' }} />
}
{% endraw %}
```